# ASP.NET MVC : Correct location for custom classes, attributes, etc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently doing a custom attribute, and did some custom classes for one of my ASP.NET MVC project.

I was wondering, is there a dedicated location to put them? I mean, some correct path naming or something.

Like controllers goes in Controllers\, models in Models\, etc...

Any suggestion is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Stuff like that should be able to go just about anywhere you feel right with, most commonly I've seen classes like that end up under a Common or Infrastructure folder and related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those attributes represent custom action filters I would put them into the `Filters` sibfolder. If they represent validator data annotations, into the `Validators` folder, ... So based on their function I would find a name.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do is add a separate library project and put them there, under descriptive folders in there, separating "MVC" from "the rest". Depending on the size of the project of course, smaller projects I would do as the previous answers and just create new folders with descriptive names.